# Query to check certain date & display one date values only

Tags: mysql

There is a table in that one date column having so many entry of totalamount at different-different time of same date but I don't worry about time. I need to find certain date all totalamount, along with username. 
When I am using below query. It shows syntax error

select username,totalamount,date from bill where date = '2013-04-12'

In the above query date is column name 
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to find all records on a given `DATE` when there is `DATETIME` saved in the db, use this method

```
SELECT username, totalamount, `date`
FROM bill 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-04-12 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-12 23:59:59'
```

If you want sum of total amount for each user on a given date

```
SELECT username, SUM(totalamount) 
FROM bill 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-04-12 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY 1
```

If you want sum of total amount for given date

```
SELECT DATE(`date`), SUM(totalamount) 
FROM bill 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-04-12 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-12 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav, sorry, that was a typo, fixed the query

Comment: Instead of SELECT you wrote SLEECT              after changing it there is no problem query is working fine thanks for helping...

Answer (score 0):

```
select username,SUM(amount), DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') date_only 
from bill 
where date = str_to_date('2013-04-12','%Y-%m-%d)
group by DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), username
```

Try this.